# Divs appear below their normal place "during the time they are displaying" with animation effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate

In the following SSCCE, on the click of `.next-arrow` and `.previous-arrow`, I am hiding and showing a few `.item` elements, four at a time (four of them are visible on the screen at a time).

I wanted to animate their showing and hiding such that it created a sliding effect of that seemingly strip of items on the screen. That is I wanted to create a horizontal sliding effect.

I found out about a bunch of options, but I want to use `animate({"width":"toggle"})` because it is the simplest. It almost serves my purpose as well.

**The only problem is that during the sliding process, the new `item`s flowing-in show up *below* the horizontal space where all the `item`s are contained.** Then once they are fully visible, and the previous group is fully invisible, they appear at their correct place.

[image]

I need them to show within the horizontal row/space enclosed by `.wrapper`, DURING THE PROCESS OF appearing as well.

**So why is this happening, and how should I fix this?**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 //alert('ready');//check
 
 var numberOfItems = $('.item').length;
 //alert('numberOfItems => ' + numberOfItems);//check
 
 displayNextArrowOnCondition();
 displayPreviousArrowOnCondition();
 
 
 
 /**
 *
 **
 $('a.next-arrow').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  
   var currentFirstItem = getCurrentFirstItem(); // Difference between var and no var SO: If you're in the global scope then there's no difference. If you're in a function then var will create a local variable, "no var" will look up the scope chain until it finds the variable or hits the global scope (at which point it will create it):
  
  $('div.item'+currentFirstItem).hide(); //We don't need to have the condition of checking this element's existence because the next-arrow whose handler this method is, appears only if the numberOfItems is greater than the id of the item with the greatest id among the elements currently visible on the screen.
  if ( ('div.item'+(currentFirstItem+1)).length ) { //SO: How can I check the existence of an element in jQuery?? In JavaScript, everything is truthy or falsy and for numbers, 0 means false, everything else true. So you could write: "if ($(selector).length)" - and you don't need that > 0 part.
   $('div.item'+(currentFirstItem+1)).hide();
  }
  if ( ('div.item'+(currentFirstItem+2)).length ) { 
   $('div.item'+(currentFirstItem+2)).hide();
  }
  if ( ('div.item'+(currentFirstItem+3)).length ) { 
   $('div.item'+(currentFirstItem+3)).hide();
  }
  
  hidePreviousArrow();
  hideNextArrow();
  
  displayPreviousArrowOnCondition();
  displayNextArrowOnCondition();
 }); */
 /**
 *
 **/
 $('a.next-arrow').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  
   var currentFirstItem = getCurrentFirstItem(); // Difference between var and no var SO: If you're in the global scope then there's no difference. If you're in a function then var will create a local variable, "no var" will look up the scope chain until it finds the variable or hits the global scope (at which point it will create it):
  
  $('div.item'+currentFirstItem).animate({"width": "toggle"}, 350); //We don't need to have the condition of checking this element's existence because the next-arrow whose handler this method is, appears only if the numberOfItems is greater than the id of the item with the greatest id among the elements currently visible on the screen.
  if ( ('div.item'+(currentFirstItem+1)).length ) { //SO: How can I check the existence of an element in jQuery?? In JavaScript, everything is truthy or falsy and for numbers, 0 means false, everything else true. So you could write: "if ($(selector).length)" - and you don't need that > 0 part.
   $('div.item'+(currentFirstItem+1)).animate({"width": "toggle"}, 350);
  }
  if ( ('div.item'+(currentFirstItem+2)).length ) { 
   $('div.item'+(currentFirstItem+2)).animate({"width": "toggle"}, 350);
  }
  if ( ('div.item'+(currentFirstItem+3)).length ) { 
   $('div.item'+(currentFirstItem+3)).animate({"width": "toggle"}, 350);
  }
  
  hidePreviousArrow();
  hideNextArrow();
  
  displayPreviousArrowOnCondition();
  displayNextArrowOnCondition();
 }); 
 
 
 /**
 *
 **
 $('a.previous-arrow').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  
   var currentFirstItem = getCurrentFirstItem(); 
  
  $('div.item'+(currentFirstItem-1)).show('slow'); 
  
  if ( ('div.item'+(currentFirstItem-2)).length ) {
   $('div.item'+(currentFirstItem-2)).show('slow');
  }
  if ( ('div.item'+(currentFirstItem-3)).length ) { 
   $('div.item'+(currentFirstItem-3)).show('slow');
  }
  if ( ('div.item'+(currentFirstItem-4)).length ) { 
   $('div.item'+(currentFirstItem-4)).show('slow');
  }
  
  hidePreviousArrow();
  hideNextArrow();
  
  displayPreviousArrowOnCondition();
  displayNextArrowOnCondition();
 });*/
 /**
 *
 **/
 $('a.previous-arrow').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  
   var currentFirstItem = getCurrentFirstItem(); 
  
  $('div.item'+(currentFirstItem-1)).animate({"width": "toggle"}, 350);
  
  if ( ('div.item'+(currentFirstItem-2)).length ) {
   $('div.item'+(currentFirstItem-2)).animate({"width": "toggle"}, 350);
  }
  if ( ('div.item'+(currentFirstItem-3)).length ) { 
   $('div.item'+(currentFirstItem-3)).animate({"width": "toggle"}, 350);
  }
  if ( ('div.item'+(currentFirstItem-4)).length ) { 
   $('div.item'+(currentFirstItem-4)).animate({"width": "toggle"}, 350);
  }
  
  hidePreviousArrow();
  hideNextArrow();
  
  displayPreviousArrowOnCondition();
  displayNextArrowOnCondition();
 });
 
 
 /**
 * DISPLAY NEXT ARROW WHEN
 * 1. NUMBER OF ITEMS IS GREATER THAN THE id OF THE LAST ITEM DISPLAYED IN THE CURRENT VIEWPORT
 **/
 function displayNextArrowOnCondition() {
  //alert('displayNextArrowOnCondition called');//check
  //Iterate through items in OPPOSTIE order, and when found the first one which is not hidden by hide() or display:none, assign it to currentLastItem (because this is the first item in the viewport), and break out from the loop.
  var currentLastItem = getCurrentLastItem();
  //alert('currentLastItem -> ' + currentLastItem);//check
  if (currentLastItem < numberOfItems) {
   $('a.next-arrow').css('display', 'block');
   $('.wrapper').mouseover(function() {
    //$('a.next-arrow').css('visibility', 'visible');
   });
   $('.wrapper').mouseleave(function() {
    //$('a.next-arrow').css('visibility', 'hidden');
   });
  }
 }
 
 
 /**
 * DISPLAY PREVIOUS ARROW WHEN
 * 1. THE id OF THE FIRST DISPLAYED ITEM IS GREATER THAN 4
 **/
 function displayPreviousArrowOnCondition() {
  //Iterate through items in order, and when found the first one which is not hidden by hide() or display:none, assign it to currentFirstItem (because this is the first item in the viewport), and break out from the loop.
  var currentFirstItem = getCurrentFirstItem();
  if (  currentFirstItem > 4  ) {
   $('a.previous-arrow').css('display', 'block');
   $('.wrapper').mouseover(function() {
    $('a.previous-arrow').css('visibility', 'visible');
   });
   $('.wrapper').mouseleave(function() {
    $('a.previous-arrow').css('visibility', 'hidden');
   });
  }
 }
 
 
 /**
 * DISPLAY:NONE NEXT ARROW IF IT IS VISIBLE
 **/
 function hideNextArrow() {
  //alert('hideNextArrow called');//check
  if ($('a.next-arrow').css('display').toLowerCase() == 'block') { //The == operator will compare for equality after doing any necessary type conversions. The === operator will not do the conversion, so if two values are not the same type === will simply return false.| Just in case anyone was wondering in 2012: === is way faster than ==. jsperf.com/comparison-of-comparisons.
   //alert('YES if ($(\'a.next-arrow\').attr(\'display\').toLowerCase() == \'block\'). SO I AM CHANGING IT TO none.');//check
   $('a.next-arrow').css('display', 'none');
  }  //else { alert('NO  if ($(\'a.next-arrow\').attr(\'display\').toLowerCase() == \'block\').'); } //check
 }
 
 
 /**
 * DISPLAY:NONE PREVIOUS ARROW IF IT IS VISIBLE
 **/
 function hidePreviousArrow() {
  //alert('hidePreviousArrow called');//check
  //alert($('a.previous-arrow').css('display'));//check
  if ($('a.previous-arrow').css('display') == 'block') {
   //alert('YES if ($(\'a.previous-arrow\').attr(\'display\').toLowerCase() == \'block\'). SO I AM CHANGING IT TO none.');//check
   $('a.previous-arrow').css('display', 'none');
  } //else { alert('NO  if ($(\'a.previous-arrow\').attr(\'display\').toLowerCase() == \'block\').'); } //check
 }
 
 
 /**
 *
 **/
 function getCurrentFirstItem() {
  for (i=1; i<=numberOfItems; i++) {
   if (  $("#"+i).visible(true, true)  ) {
    //alert('YES if (  $("#"+i).visible(true, true)  )');//check
    currentFirstItem = i;
    break;
   } //else { //alert('NO if (  $("#"+i).visible(true, true)  )'); }//check 
  }
  //alert('currentFirstItem -> ' + currentFirstItem);//check
  return currentFirstItem;
 }
 
 
 /**
 *
 **/
 function getCurrentLastItem() {
  for (j=numberOfItems; j>=1; j--) {
   if (  $("#"+j).visible(true, true) )  {
    //alert("YES if (  $(\"#\"+j).visible(true, true) ) ");//check
    currentLastItem = j;
    break;
   } //else { //alert('NO if (  $("#"+j).visible(true, true) )'); } //check
  }
  //alert('currentLastItem -> ' + currentLastItem);//check
  return currentLastItem;
 }
 
});
```

```css
html, body, body div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, abbr, address, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp, small, strong, sub, sup, var, b, i, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, time, mark, audio, video, details, summary {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px none;
    background: transparent none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

.wrapper {
 position:relative;
 white-space:nowrap;
 overflow:hidden;
}

div.item {
 /*position:absolute;*/
 display:inline-block;
 width:25%;
 height:25vw;
}


.item1 {
 left:0%;
 background-color:wheat;
}.item2 {
 left:25%;
 background-color:pink;
}.item3 {
 left:50%;
 background-color:beige;
}.item4 {
 left:75%;
 background-color:gainsboro;
}.item5 {
 left:100%;
 background-color:coral;
}.item6 {
 left:125%;
 background-color:crimson;
} .item7 {
 left:150%;
 background-color:aquamarine;
} .item8 {
 left:175%;
 background-color:darkgoldenrod;
}.item9 {
 left:200%;
 background-color:khaki;
}.item10 {
 left:225%;
 background-color:indianred;
}.item11 {
 left:250%;
 background-color:mediumspringgreen;
} 



.previous-arrow, .next-arrow {
 width:30px;
 height:50%;
 top:50%;
 position:absolute;
 opacity:0.7;
 color:white;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 margin-top: -30px;
 
 display:none;
}

.previous-arrow {
 background-image:url(a2.png);
 left:0px;
}

.next-arrow {
 background-image:url(b2.png);
 right:0px;
}

.previous-arrow, .next-arrow {
 opacity:1;
}

body {
 background-color:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.visible/1.1.0/jquery.visible.min.js"></script>


<div class="wrapper"><!--
  --><a class="previous-arrow" href="">&lt;</a>--><!--
  --><div id="1" class="item item1 wheat">a.</div><!--
  --><div id="2" class="item item2 pink">a.</div><!--
  --><div id="3" class="item item3 beige">a.</div><!--
  --><div id="4" class="item item4 gainsboro">a.</div><!--
  --><div id="5" class="item item5 coral">a.</div><!--
  --><div id="6" class="item item6 crimson">a.</div><!--
  --><div id="7" class="item item7 darkgoldenrod">a.</div><!--
  --><div id="8" class="item item8 aquamarine">a.</div><!--
  --><div id="9" class="item item9 aquamarine">a.</div><!--
  --><div id="10" class="item item10 aquamarine">a.</div><!--
  --><div id="11" class="item item11 aquamarine">a.</div><!--
  --><a class="next-arrow" href="">&lt;</a>
  
 </div>
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem but I notice you have a lot of commented out alert calls with debug information. The function console.log is a far less intrusive alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animation adds overflow: hidden which seems to affect the vertical alignment when combined with vertical-align: baseline. Adding overflow: hidden to all the items fixes it:

```
div.item {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Or, if you don't want overflow hidden on all the items, you can set the vertical align to something other than baseline:

```
div.item {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```